# Как выбрать ID товаров woocommerce оригинал и перевод (с помощью плагина Polylang)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здраствуйте.

Как известно плагин Polylang при создании перевода товара , создает новый товар, в котором вы пишете перевод.
Причем в списке товаров выводится ссылка на перевод в одном языке, и перевод в другом языке.
Появилась потребность вывести ID товара и ID его перевода.
Так вот, в какой таблице хранятся данные о ID оригинала и ID перевода.
И как это черт возьми сделать.

Answer (score 2):

ID товара хранится вместе с другими характеристиками товара. Там, где вы выводите товар используйте `$product_id = $product->get_id()`.

Далее надо обратиться к функции Polylang и получить все переводы товара:

```
$translations = pll_get_post_translations( $product_id );
```

Полученный ассоциативный массив содержит слаги языков как ключи и переводы (товар на других языках) как значения. В том числе, и ID каждого перевода.

Answer (score 0):

Надо смотреть табличку wp_term_taxonomy, где `taxonomy` = 'post_translations'
поле description.

Comment: Табличку смотреть не надо. Забудьте эту привычку лазить руками в базу. Во-первых, это недокументированная возможность. Сегодня таблицы плагины такие, а завтра другие. Во-вторых, есть объектный кеш, и информация в базе не всегда совпадает с текущим состоянием объектов в памяти.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Согласен, но как раз такой вариант, что проще исправить ошибки в базе.

Comment: Исправить?? В базе?? Прямой путь к разрушенному сайту. А потом нам говорят, что WP - это дно.

Comment: Ситуация такая. Пользователь установил плагин пиратский, который добавляет аренду к вукомерс. Добавил товаров, не прочитав инструкцию. По инструкции надо сначала добавлять inventory, где указывать количество доступных товаров. Он такого не делал, теперь надо или пересоздавать все товары через интерфейс иои в базу лезть.
Товаров там больше 1000. Вообщем запутано все , плагин RnB woocommerce.